# Split tabular cell and duplicate cell content across page

Tags: tables, page-breaking

Given a table with content as follows:[image]

Is it possible to define the table columns such that the typesetting system automatically splits the content in Column 3 if it will overflow? Additionally, is it possible to in such a scenario define the table such that the items in column 1 and 2 will be duplicated?

In the MWE below, I manually split the cell content into 2 cells, but ideally, it should also work with 1 cell.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,longtable, lipsum}
\begin{document}
Text First Line
\vspace{26cm}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{|m{3cm}|m{3.5cm}|p{12cm}|}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \centering \textbf{Heading}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Item 1} & \textbf{Item 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Item 3 (Long)}} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \centering \textbf{Heading (continued)}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Item 1} & \textbf{Item 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Item 3 (Long)}} \\
    \endhead
    A & B & This is the content in the first cell. This remains the content in the first cell. It may seem utterly implausible, but this content is still within the \\ \hline
    A (continued) & B (continued) & confines of the first cell. \\ \hline
    C & D & This is the second cell \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, the same behaviour would be obtainable so you could write

```
<table declaration>
A & B & This is the content in the first cell. This remains the content in the first cell. It may seem utterly implausible, but this content is still within the confines of the first cell \\ \hline
```

and still have the same output as in the attached image.

Comment: `longtable` can only insert pagebreaks between rows, not within.

Comment: And are there no alternatives with which I can replace longtable to achieve the desired effect? @leandriis